# hide a sub report containing a chart pentaho

Tags: pentaho

Hi we are using Pentaho report designer and we want to hide a subreport if there is no data .

We have  tried to use this formula :

```
not(isemptydata())
```

in the visible expression but it does not seem to work .

So how to hide a subreport if no data .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using all small letters like **not(isemptydata())**. You can't use like that all are capitals like **=NOT(ISEMPTYDATA())**. You add this line to your report it will work i think.

Otherwise also you can hide that sub report **=IF(ISEMPTYDATA();"False"; "True")**.

Thank you..

Comment: I have just tested: concatenate() function is not case-sensitive. I doubt that other functions are.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `=NOT(ISEMPTYDATA())` formula on `sub-report-active` attribute of your subreport. This attribute can be modified on "Attributes" tab under "common" attributes group:

[image: location of the attribute in PRD gui]

As far as I understand "visible" property uses the dataset of the parent sub-report, while sub-report-active uses the data-set of the current sub-report. (See Taqua's post #6 in http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?62194-Hide-a-Subreport-if-No-Data/page2)

Comment: i have this warning;  WARNING: Element '' with expression on attribute 'sub-report-active' has no value for mandatory property 'Fail On Error'. i have set the property to true

Comment: So, even after setting the expression for sub-report-active you still see your subreport with empty data, right? Please place somewhere a label with the same expression on `value` attribute and check if the label displays `false` for empty dataset. That's all just to make sure that your dataset is really empty and the expression has no errors.

Comment: dataset is really empty and the chart showing no data it is not hiding at all